# Inserir o valor de uma String do Javascript em um arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código Javascript:

```js
// Converts XML to JSON
// from: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/convert-xml-json-javascript_s2
function XMLtoJSON() {
    var me = this; // stores the object instantce

    // gets the content of an xml file and returns it in 
    me.fromFile = function(xml, rstr) {
        // Cretes a instantce of XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        // sets and sends the request for calling "xml"
        xhttp.open("GET", xml, false);
        xhttp.send(null);

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xhttp.responseXML));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // returns XML DOM from string with xml content
    me.fromStr = function(xml, rstr) {
        // for non IE browsers
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var getxml = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = getxml.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        } else {
            // for Internet Explorer
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
        }

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xmlDoc));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // receives XML DOM object, returns converted JSON object
    var setJsonObj = function(xml) {
        var js_obj = {};
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
                js_obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    js_obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.value;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
            js_obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    js_obj[nodeName] = setJsonObj(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = js_obj[nodeName];
                        js_obj[nodeName] = [];
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    js_obj[nodeName].push(setJsonObj(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return js_obj;
    }

    // converts JSON object to string (human readablle).
    // Removes '\t\r\n', rows with multiples '""', multiple empty rows, '  "",', and "  ",; replace empty [] with ""
    var jsontoStr = function(js_obj) {
        var rejsn = JSON.stringify(js_obj, undefined, 2).replace(/(\\t|\\r|\\n)/g, '').replace(/"",[\n\t\r\s]+""[,]*/g, '').replace(/(\n[\t\s\r]*\n)/g, '').replace(/[\s\t]{2,}""[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/"[\s\t]{1,}"[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/\[[\t\s]*\]/g, '""');
        return (rejsn.indexOf('"parsererror": {') == -1) ? rejsn : 'Invalid XML format';
    }
};

// creates object instantce of XMLtoJSON
var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
```

Esse código é interpretado no meu index.html através do código:

```html
<body>
    <h4>Result JSON</h4>
    <pre id="jsnstr"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        // gets the JSON string from a file with XML content ("test.xml")
        var jsonstr = xml2json.fromFile('arquivo.xml', 'string');

        // adds the JSON string in HTML element with id="jsnstr"
        document.getElementById('jsnstr').innerHTML = jsonstr;
        // ]]>
    </script>
</body>
```

Alguém pode me indicar uma forma de eu inserir o valor do "jsnstr" dentro de um arquivo.txt(Sendo que o código vai criar o arquivo)?
Devo usar php para isso ? Jquery ?
Qual a forma mais simples?

Answer (score -1):

até onde sei não é possível fazer a gravação de arquivos no servidor usando somente javascript.

Você vai precisar criar um script PHP que ficara responsável por salvar o arquivo no servidor, algo como:

```
$file = fopen("upload/arquivo.txt", 'w');// Cria um novo arquivo
fwrite($file, $data); // Insere o conteúdo
fclose($file);
```

A partir dai você poderia mandar o conteúdo que quer salvar via Ajax pro script PHP.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: quanto a criar usando javascript eu já sabia, esse código que você me enviou eu estava testando mas sem sucesso, usei da seguinte forma:      "<?php
$convert = "<script>document.write(jsonstr)</script>";
$myfile = fopen("m_visa.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = convert;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>"  porém não funcionou ou eu não soube como fazer. Como devo fazer pra funcionar via ajax ?

Comment: Não dá pra passar a string pro PHP usando "document.write". Faça uma requisição post via AJAX, passando a string como parâmetro, para um script PHP que a recebe no array $_POST e aí sim escreve em arquivo como o @BrunoM recomendou. =)